# Android 4.0.3 emulator crashes: Failed to allocate memory: 8

Tags: android, android-emulator

The problem started when I changed the skin built-in display setting to WXGA720.
Then everytime I'm trying to run the emulator it says the following message:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'android403'
>   Failed to allocate memory: 8
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I already tried to lower down the RAM size to 800 MB and then 512 MB (or even 256) but it didn't work either...

I don't know what to do...

Here's a screenshot of the emulator settings window:

[image]

Thanx upfront.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I do sometimes have the same problem. Maybe my solution works for you as well: Instead of choosing the WXGA720 skin preset, manually set the resolution to 720*1280, and manually set the RAM to 768 or even 512.
Seems stupid, but it makes a difference if the skin preset is uses or a manual resolution configuration.

Comment: Setting the resolution manually was all it took. How make is that? :-( Thanks though, would have NEVER figured this out by myself!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I have set the resolution manually to `720 X 1280`. Set the RAM size as `128MB` and SSD to `16 MB`. The app came up without any problems after that

Comment: Changing the RAM size did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

This may sound silly, but I resolved the issue by adding "MB" after the RAM setting, changing (for example) 1024 to 1024MB.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The problem was in the amount of ram I had specified for the virtual machine, and it was 1024MB, now I have 512MB and it is ok. enjoy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem for x86 emulator for android 4.0.3. This problems happens to me only when i try to launch emulator from eclipse. But works fine when i launched the emulator from command line. Try to launch the emulator from command line.

Go to android tool directory and use "emulator -avd " to launch your emulator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, trying to emulate the Galaxy S3.  Setting the resolution to 720 x 1280 and dropping ram from 1024 to 700 worked for me.  Could't get it to work at all on the built in wxga720 settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem today, but I manage how to solve it ( at least for me, because I was doing it in the wrong way), hope that it can be usefull for you too.

I was trying to change de Device RAM memory direct by Eclipse via Android Virtual Device Manager. I don't know why, but this changes does not affect the "hardware.ini" file that is present in :   \android-sdk\platforms\android-16\skins\WXGA800-7in  , for example.
To change the device RAM, or just to add MB you need to change this file.