# Jelly Beans and ICS Emulators not Opening

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm use Eclipse IDE and added the ADT Plugin. I created the Emulator for Android 2.2 Froyo,2.3 Ginger Bread,4.0 ICS,4.1 Jelly Beans.

Here Froyo and Ginger are working fine, when i start ICS Emulator Its take too long to start working very slow and Jelly beans not yet working. When i start the Jelly Beans Emulator getting error like this,

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'JF'
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

My system configuration is Ram 4GB Core i5 64 bit Window XP SP2

Comment: @Somnath: Did you made any changes on my question?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Please solve my problem

Comment: have you tried to update/reinstall the sdk manager ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes i reinstalled twice

Comment: This link works for me [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318348/android-4-0-3-emulator-crashes-failed-to-allocate-memory-8][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318348/android-4-0-3-emulator-crashes-failed-to-allocate-memory-8

But still some more problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the memory allocated? Maybe to 256, 512 or 1024?

Also you might want to [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory).